# Ruby--> How can I set an arguement to require a range

Tags: ruby

```
def input_to_index(user_input = 1..9)
     @user_input.to_i - 1
   end
```

I need the argument to be from 1-9 only and be inputted as a strong originally. I know the code I put in the argument is incorrect for sure, I'm just not sure what to put in there to specify it can only be a range of 1-9.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy, all you have to do is use `raise` with proper condition:

```
def input_to_index(user_input)
  user_input = user_input.to_i
  raise ArgumentError unless (1..9).include?(user_input)

  user_input - 1
end
```

This way, the method will raise `ArgumentError` every time when input argument is invalid. You can description as a second argument to `raise`, like this:

```
 raise ArgumentError, 'Input should be in range 1-9' unless (1..9).include?(user_input)
```

Comment: Thank you Marek was really stuck on this for a little.

Comment: Consider `user_input #=> "9 cats"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def input_to_index(user_input)
  raise ArgumentError unless user_input.match?(/\A[1-9]\z/)
  user_input.to_i - 1
end
```

```
input_to_index('3')
  #=> 2
input_to_index('0')
  #=> ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
input_to_index('10')
  #=> ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
input_to_index('3 blind mice')
  #=> ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
```

The regular expression matches a string consisting of one digit between `'1'` and `'9'`. `\A` and `\z` are *anchors* corresponding to the beginning and end of the string, respectively. `[1-9]` is a *character class* that matches one of the characters between `1` and `9` (the same as `[123456789]`). See [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) and [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html).